# Deserialization In Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I serialized a file with multiple objects.  So I wrote a code like below -

```
FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File("Output.ser"));
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee2);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee3);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee4);
objectOutputStream.close();
```

Now I want to de-serialize it, so to do that I took the help of WHILE loop to loop through all the objects ! The Code looks like below -

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
ObjectInputStream stream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
Employee emp;
while((emp=(Employee) stream.readObject())!=null)
{
    String uName=emp.getUserId();
    String uPass=emp.getPassword();
    map.put(uName, uPass);
}
```

This code making an EOFException reaching the end of file. I guess readObject() should return a null when it reaches the end of the file but in this case it ended up throwing an exception!
*Please do suggest me way(s) by which I can successfully read my serialized file without getting any exception!*

Comment: Why not serialise a list, then deserialise a list. That way you don't have to worry about the while loop at all

Comment: I never tried that using a list object. But when this normal object cant be completely deserialised without exceptions will a list object can show any change?? I doubt,but I will try that! Problem is not object problem is reading an object and reaching EOF! @RichardTingle

Comment: Use a list, serialize it and use a for-each statement when you deserialize it (`for(Object object : myListWithTheObjects)`)

Comment: Your problems are caused by trying to deserialise an unknown number of objects. Which can be done but causes unnecessary complication. with a list you know how many objects you're deserialising: exactly 1

Comment: p.s I'm assumming it would be a List<Employee> rather than a List<Object>

Comment: I wrote `Object` to give an idea about what is a for-each statement, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of serializing multiple objects, you should serialize a `List` like so :

```
FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File("Output.ser"));
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(employee);
employees.add(employee2);
employees.add(employee3);
employees.add(employee4);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employees);
objectOutputStream.close();
```

You can deserialize it like so :

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
ObjectInputStream stream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
for(Employee emp : (ArrayList)stream.readObject())
{
    String uName = emp.getUserId();
    String uPass = emp.getPassword();
    map.put(uName, uPass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `stream.readObject()` will not return `null` when you reach the End of File. It will throw an `EOFExcpetion` to indicate that.

Your number of reads should basically match the number of writes. If you `readObject` in a loop you will face the `EOFException`.

Options you have are:

1. Have as many `readObject` calls as `writeObject` calls by keeping a tab on number of objects written.
2. Store in a List as @Richard has mentioned and call `readObject` once.
3. In your posted implementation handle `EOFException` and do what you need to do when end of file has reached and close the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use Collection Framework (e.g. `ArrayList`) or any other object which can encapsulate many objects when you want to serialize more than 1 objects.
But to work it your way, you have to give your serialized file a standard. You may add first object as an `Integer` which will tell you how much objects are stored in your file.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File("Output.ser"));
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(new Integer(4));
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee2);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee3);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee4);
objectOutputStream.close();
```

When desirializing, you can get the number of objects serialized.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
ObjectInputStream stream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
Employee emp;
Integer size = (Integer) stream.readObject();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Employee emp = (Employee) stream.readObject();
    String uName=emp.getUserId();
    String uPass=emp.getPassword();
    map.put(uName, uPass);
}
```

It is a normal method how many files are stored in your filesystem but here you are doing it externally for your own purpose. Remember you will have to do necessary exception handling if you decide to work this way.